# Invalid json while trying gcloud functions commands via javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, jestjs, google-cloud-functions, child-process

I am trying to run a sample test using Jest to verify if my Google Cloud Function is working fine or not but I am constantly getting following error.

I have tried running the following command directly in windows power shell but still the same error which can be escaped using \ before double quotes.

```
Error: Command failed: gcloud beta functions call cf-1 --region europe-west1 --data '{"data":"eyJkYXRhIjoiMSJ9"}'
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.call) Invalid value for [--data]: Is not a valid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded
```

**test file**

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');

describe('Test CF', () => {
    it('print outs the error message when received JSON is blank', done => {
        const msg = { data: '1' };
        const encodedMsg = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(msg)).toString('base64');
        const data = JSON.stringify({ data: encodedMsg });
        const executeResultOutput = childProcess.execSync(`gcloud beta functions call cf-1 --region europe-west1 --data '${data}'`).toString();

        const logs = childProcess
            .execSync(
                `gcloud functions logs read cf-1 --region europe-west1 --execution-id ${executionIdObj}`,
            )
            .toString();

        expect(logs).toEqual(expect.stringContaining('Error..'));
    });
});
```

**Update#1:** Still the same issue...

[image]

Comment: This does not answer your question, but note that you cannot call `gcloud` from your code running in Cloud Functions.

Comment: @JohnHanley my intention is not to call gcloud from with in the cloud function. I was following an article from [google](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-background) which gives insight into testing cloud functions so I will run the code locally and will test the cloud functions deployed in cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to replicate your situation and the issue you're experiencing by doing the following:

First, I deployed a simple **Cloud Function** using Node.js 8:

```
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.simpleFunction = (req, res) => {
  let data = req.query.data || req.body.data || 'Didn\'t work!';
  res.status(200).send(data);
};
```

After that, I followed a Google Cloud Platform [Quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart) to create a simple **Node.js app**, which I then modified to call my function locally. I have added some lines of the code, which you have in your example to call the function:

```
'use strict';
 
// [START gae_node_request_example]
const express = require('express');
const childProcess = require('child_process');
 
const app = express();

// The lines you used for a function call 
const msg = { data: '1' };
const encodedMsg = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(msg)).toString('base64');
const data = JSON.stringify({ data: encodedMsg });
const executeResultOutput = childProcess.execSync(`gcloud beta functions call b-func --region us-central1 --data '${data}'`).toString();
 
 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .send(executeResultOutput)
    .end();
});
 
// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});
// [END gae_node_request_example]
 
module.exports = app;
```

The code above worked for me and here is the **output** that I received:

```
executionId: 6n6pf9720dsj result: eyJtZXNzYWdlIjoiMSJ9
```

---

The only time I was able to get the same **ERROR** as yours: `Is not a valid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded` was when I passed the **data value** without surrounding it with quotes:

```
const data = {"data":"some data"};
const executeResultOutput = childProcess.execSync(`gcloud beta functions call b-func --region us-central1 --data '${data}'`).toString();
```

---

### Edit:

I have tested the code that I mentioned above in **Linux** environment. Once I tried to run it in **Windows** I got the same error.

Since the code is being run locally, **PowerShell** still will need to escape the parameters as John pointed out.

As I see you've opened a new [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994072/escaping-double-quotes-in-windows-commands) regarding this issue already. Try the solution that was offered there - it worked for me.

Comment: I will try this again soon and will c what's wrong with my code. BTW did u run this on Windows?

Answer (score 6):

The command line syntax that you are using is for Linux.

Change the `--data` part to this for Windows:

```
--data "{\"data\":\"eyJkYXRhIjoiMSJ9\"}"
```

Note that you have to escape quote marks.

Comment: thanks, i missed mentioning that I know how to make it work from cmd line but somehow i don't find any way to do the same in javascript

Comment: You need to change your question to match the answer that you need. Your question is about invalid JSON, which I answered.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, especially when I wanted to pass multiple variables in my data argument:

To send the following JSON:

```
 {"key":"val", "key2":"val2"}
```

I appended it as follows

```
gcloud functions call function-name --data "{\"key\":\"val\", \"key2\":\"val2\"}"
```