# Escaping double quotes in windows commands

Tags: javascript, windows, child-process

I am trying to run a sample test using Jest to verify if my Google Cloud Function is working fine or not but I am constantly getting following error.

> Error: Command failed: gcloud beta functions call cf-1 --region europe-west1 --data '{"data":"eyJkYXRhIjoiMSJ9"}'
>   ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.call) Invalid value for [--data]: Is not a valid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

I know that i can escape double quotes with backslash when running the command in windows terminal but how to do it in JavaScript.

**test.js**

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');

describe('Test CF', () => {
    it('print outs the error message when received JSON is blank', done => {
        const msg = { data: '1' };
        const encodedMsg = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(msg)).toString('base64');
        const data = JSON.stringify({ data: encodedMsg });
        const executeResultOutput = childProcess.execSync(`gcloud beta functions call cf-1 --region europe-west1 --data '${data}'`).toString();

        const logs = childProcess
            .execSync(
                `gcloud functions logs read cf-1 --region europe-west1 --execution-id ${executionIdObj}`,
            )
            .toString();

        expect(logs).toEqual(expect.stringContaining('Error..'));
    });
});
```

Comment: FYI, in Windows, except for initial quoting around the executable path, which is significant to `CreateProcessW`, the meaning of double or single quotes and how to escape them is up to the application. Most follow [VC++ rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/parsing-cpp-command-line-arguments?view=vs-2019). This is in sharp contrast to Unix, in which the parent controls how a command line gets parsed into arguments for an `exec*` system call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it twice:

```js
data = {"data":"eyJkYXRhIjoiMSJ9"}
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(data))
)
```